# iTextSharp v5 - How do you concatenate PDFs in memory?

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7

I am having trouble merging PDFs in-memory. I have 2 memory streams, a **master** and **component** stream, the idea is that as each component PDF is built up, the component PDF's bytes are added to the master stream. At the very end of all the components, we have a byte array that's a PDF.

I have the code below, but nothing is copying into my `masterStream`. I think the issue is with `CopyPagesTo`, but I'm not familiar enough and the documentation/examples are hard to find.

```
byte[] updated;
using (MemoryStream masterMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    masterStream.WriteTo(masterMemoryStream);

    // Read from master stream (ie. all existing components)
    masterMemoryStream.Position = 0;
    using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter masterPdfWriter = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(masterMemoryStream))
    using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument masterPdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(masterPdfWriter))
    {


        using (MemoryStream componentMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            componentStream.WriteTo(componentMemoryStream);

            // Read from new component
            componentMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader componentPdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(componentMemoryStream))
            using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument componentPdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(componentPdfReader))
            {
                // Copy pages from component into master
                componentPdfDocument.CopyPagesTo(1, componentPdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(), masterPdfDocument);
            }
        }
    }

    updated = masterMemoryStream.GetBuffer();
}

// Write updates to master stream?
masterStream.SetLength(0);
using (MemoryStream temp = new MemoryStream(updated))
    temp.WriteTo(masterStream);
```

## Answer

This is mkl's answer with some of my corrections:

```cs
using (MemoryStream temporaryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    masterStream.Position = 0;
    componentStream.Position = 0;
    using (PdfDocument combinedDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(masterStream), new PdfWriter(temporaryStream)))
    using (PdfDocument componentDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(componentStream)))
    {
        componentDocument.CopyPagesTo(1, componentDocument.GetNumberOfPages(), combinedDocument);
    }
    byte[] temporaryBytes = temporaryStream.ToArray();
    masterStream.Position = 0;
    masterStream.SetLength(temporaryBytes.Length);
    masterStream.Capacity = temporaryBytes.Length;
    masterStream.Write(temporaryBytes, 0, temporaryBytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code. I'll first give you a working version and then go into the issues in your code.

## A working version (with an important limitation)

You can combine two PDFs given in `MemoryStream` instances `masterStream` and `componentStream` and get the result in the same `MemoryStream` instance `masterStream` as follows:

```c#
using (MemoryStream temporaryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    masterStream.Position = 0;
    componentStream.Position = 0;
    using (PdfDocument combinedDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(masterStream), new PdfWriter(temporaryStream)))
    using (PdfDocument componentDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(componentStream)))
    {
        componentDocument.CopyPagesTo(1, componentDocument.GetNumberOfPages(), combinedDocument);
    }
    byte[] temporaryBytes = temporaryStream.ToArray();
    masterStream.Position = 0;
    masterStream.Capacity = temporaryBytes.Length;
    masterStream.Write(temporaryBytes, 0, temporaryBytes.Length);
    masterStream.Position = 0;
}
```

The **limitation** is that you have to have instantiated the `masterStream` *with an **expandable** capacity*; the `MemoryStream` class has a number of constructors only some of which create such an expandable instance while the others create *non-resizable* instances. For details read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream).

## Issues in your concept and code

#### Concatenating PDF files does not result in a valid merged PDF

You describe your concept like this

> the idea is that as each component PDF is built up, the component PDF's bytes are added to the master stream

This does not work, though, the PDF format does not allow merging PDFs by simply concatenating them. In particular the (active) objects in a PDF have an identifier number which must be unique in the PDF, concatenating would result in a file with non-unique object identifiers; PDFs contain cross reference structures which map each object identifier to its offset from the file start, concatenating would get all these offsets wrong for the added PDFs; furthermore, a PDF has to have a single root object from which the other objects are referenced directly or indirectly, concatenating would result in multiple root objects.

#### Writing and immediately overwriting

In your code you have

```c#
masterStream.WriteTo(masterMemoryStream);

// Read from master stream (ie. all existing components)
masterMemoryStream.Position = 0;
using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter masterPdfWriter = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(masterMemoryStream))
```

Here you write the contents of `masterStream` to `masterMemoryStream`, then set the `masterMemoryStream` position to the start and instantiate a `PdfWriter` which starts writing there. I.e. your original copy of the `masterStream` contents get overwritten, surely not what you wanted.

#### Using `MemoryStream.GetBuffer`

`MemoryStream.GetBuffer` does not only return the data written into the `MemoryStream` by design but the whole buffer; i.e. there may be a lot of trash bytes after the actual PDF in what you retrieve here

```c#
updated = masterMemoryStream.GetBuffer();
```

This may cause PDF processors trying to process your result PDFs to be unable to open the file: PDFs have a pointer to the last cross references at their end, so if you have trash bytes following the actual end of your PDF, PDF processors may not find that pointer.

## PS

As worked out in the comments, the code above works fine in case of constantly growing stream lengths (which usually will happen in the use case at hand) but in general one needs to restrict the stream size before writing the new content, e.g. like this:

```c#
...
masterStream.Position = 0;
masterStream.SetLength(temporaryBytes.Length); // <<<<
masterStream.Capacity = temporaryBytes.Length;
...
```

Comment: Incredible, such detail you put into your answer, thank you. I was confused understanding at what positions and order I needed to set up the PdfReader/Writers so thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Your additional information about PDF unique ids and .GetBuffer was also helpful.

For your code, I found I needed to set the Length explicitly (setting the capacity wasn't enough) and setting `masterStream.Position = 0;` wasn't necessary at the end. Other than this detail, thank you.

Comment: *"I found I needed to set the Length explicitly (setting the capacity wasn't enough)"* - that is interesting as I tested the code above before posting it and it did work. *"setting masterStream.Position = 0; wasn't necessary"* - that's quite possible, I added the position setting lines quite generously.

Comment: It worked originally for me as well too, but then I found a particular PDF where it was trying to set the capacity to a value that was smaller than the length.

Comment: Ah, ok. I assumed only growing streams due to the merging, but different PDF producers might compress differently, resulting in an issue...

Comment: Yep! There's on addendum, it's actually .SetLength([length]) as opposed to .Length = [length].

Comment: Oops. Corrected.